# python: while loop not met if condition

Tags: python-3.x

I'm try to write a code about enter the password. The user has three attempt to enter the password. If the new attempt is correct or the user has tried 3 times total, the loop should end. However, my code can't run the part for enter the correct password.Then, how can I get rid of the break? Please help me!

```
passwd='pass1'

enter=input('Please enter the password:')

counter = 0

while counter in range(3):

if counter==0:

  if enter==passwd:

     print('Access granted')

     break

  elif enter!=passwd:

     result=input('That is incorrect, please try again:')

     counter=counter+1

elif counter==1:

  if enter==passwd:

     print('Access granted')

     break
  elif enter!=passwd:

     result=input('That is incorrect, please try again:')

     counter=counter+1

elif counter==2:

  if enter==passwd:

    print('Access granted')

    break

 elif enter!=passwd:

    print('Access denied')

    counter=counter+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write

```
passwd='pass1'

enter=input('Please enter the password:')

counter = 0
flag = False

while counter in range(3):


  if enter==passwd:

     print('Access granted')
     flag = True

     break

  elif enter!=passwd:

     result=input('That is incorrect, please try again:')

     counter=counter+1

if not Flag:
  print("3 attempts exhausted")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
pass = ‘pass1’
count = 0
while count in range(3):
    enter = input(‘insert password: ‘)
    if enter == pass:
       print(‘Access Granted’)
       break
    else:
       print(‘invalid password’)
       count+=1
```

In your code your using ‘enter’ to hold the input and then result. After the first pass ‘enter’ never changed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looping based on the desired result, not the counter:

```
counter = 1
passwd  = 'pass1'
enter   = ''

while enter != passwd:
    enter = input('Please enter the password:')
    if (enter != passwd):
        counter += 1
        if (counter > 3):
            print("Access denied")
            break
        else:
            print('That is incorrect, please try again:')
    else:
        print("Access is granted")
```

I tried to keep your same messages, this made the code a little more complex.  Obviously it could be reduced further by simplifying the steps needed.